# UIScrollView zoom behaviour WITHOUT scaling subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

So I have a `UIScrollView` with the zooming functionality delegated to a view controller which of course overrides:

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView { ... etc ...
```

and everything works (it zooms and scrolls).

Then I took it up a notch an added two other UIScrollViews to the top level view whose purposes is to act as guides for a grid (think rows and columns in M$ Excel for example).

Therefore one of the scrollView's subview contains a row of `UILabel`s (A, B, C, D...) and the other is identical except the `UILabel`s are in a column (1, 2, 3, 4...). Picture a chess board if this helps.

Now I connected the vertical and horizontal scrolling of the main scrollView to the guide scroll views like so:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == self.scrollView) {
       self.verticalGuideScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
       self.horizontalGuideScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
    }
}
```

And everything works.

I connected the zooming functionality of the scrollView's like so:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == self.scrollView) {
        self.verticalGuideScrollView.zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale;
        self.horizontalGuideScrollView.zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale;
    }
}
```

and that also works fine EXCEPT I don't actually want it to enlarge the subviews (i.e the `UILabel`s) in the guide views, I merely want the translation behaviour that comes from zooming without the scaling (enlarging or shrinking).

I can envision a solution by adding a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`to the main scrollView and using that to translate all the subviews in the guide scroll views but perhaps someone here can come up with something simpler.

Comment: How about adding A sublayer and add labels inside the sublayer.

Comment: You mean like a CALayer? Yes I suppose it is fundamentally just animation, I'll take a crack at it and get back to you.